# How we can click on 'Href' link under Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on the href link as per attached image, And I've tried the below code but seems like it's not working. Please help me.

.....

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='Careers']")).click();

............

Here is HTML content for Div tag...
..............

```
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="/ui/healthcare/assets/images/core/ascension_logo_white.svg" alt="Ascension">
    </div>


    <ul class="list-group">
            <li>
                <h4>Get Involved</h4>
                <ul class="link-list">
                            <li><a href="/Careers">Careers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Events">Classes and Events</a></li>
```

........................

.....[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below xpath

```
 driver.get("https://healthcare.ascension.org/"); 
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver); 
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"); 
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/Careers']")));
```

Comment: It's not working, It's showing 'Element is not displayed'

Comment: if it is not working check the if there any `iframe` if it is you have to switch to iframe first.

Comment: for above code, It's showing the time out error - Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //a[text()[contains(.,'Careers')]] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189672/discussion-between-kajal-kundu-and-ajay-kumar).